# spark DistributedLDAModel and LocalLDAModel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lda

I'm trying to train a topic model to cluster and topic bunch of documents.
My training codes are shown below, iteration times will be set as 20 as default. The optimizer will be EM as default.

```
val ldaModel = new LDA().
            setK(500).setOptimizer("em").run(corpus)))
```

then I picked up a doc in my training docs to check its topics, by using

```
val topicsA = ldaModel.topicDistributions.filter(x=>x._1 == 100)
```

secondly, I find the words vec for this doc, and use LocalLDAModel to predict its topics.

```
val topicsB = ldaModel.toLocal.topicDistribution(wordsVec)
```

but I got 2 completely different topics distributions for topicsA and topicsB..

I'm kinda lost here, any suggestions?

And one more thing, how to choose an optimizer between EM and Online? Seems like if you need more mini-batch data to be added in later after you have trained your model, Online is a better and memory-save option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing out a guess here, but is it possible that the topic ids are not preserved by `toLocal`?  In `DistributedLDAModel.topicsMatrix` it warns

> No guarantees are given about the ordering of the topics.

So maybe you are actually getting the same distribution both ways, but it's been permuted.

Comment: yeah I think that's the reason, LocalLDAModel. topicDistributions is predicting by using this topicsMatrix.
Thanks!